# Problems with Eclipse (and m2eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, m2eclipse

I use Eclipse and I have serious problems :-( First I try to reconstruct my situation rudely for you:

1. I installed Eclipse Java EE Helios and JDK 1.6.0_21 and configured windows' system vaariables
2. I installed m2eclipse
3. I generated an archetype for a JSF Webproject

I use Windows XP Professional SP3

So... now Eclipse has very big problems. When I try to open the pom.xml or use some maven specific options eclipse stops working and a permgen space error occures, like here in my last session:

```
!SESSION 2010-07-12 16:45:23.671 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2010-07-12 16:45:24.796
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2010-07-12 16:54:53.046
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:469)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.copyMenu(ActionContributionItem.java:1270)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleShowProxy(ActionContributionItem.java:1248)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$4(ActionContributionItem.java:1237)
 at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$8.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:1210)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_INITMENUPOPUP(Control.java:4485)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4188)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1598)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2038)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
 at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.TrackPopupMenu(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu._setVisible(Menu.java:256)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2010-07-12 16:54:53.046
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Periodic workspace save.".
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:469)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.saveVariablesAndContainers(JavaModelManager.java:3819)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.saving(JavaModelManager.java:4065)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.executeLifecycle(SaveManager.java:361)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager$1.run(SaveManager.java:170)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.broadcastLifecycle(SaveManager.java:173)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1108)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.SaveManager.save(SaveManager.java:1087)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.DelayedSnapshotJob.run(DelayedSnapshotJob.java:44)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2010-07-12 16:54:56.109
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler.getMethodToExecute(WidgetMethodHandler.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler.isHandled(WidgetMethodHandler.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler.updateEnablement(WidgetMethodHandler.java:57)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler$1.handleEvent(WidgetMethodHandler.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1253)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.sendFocusEvent(Control.java:2618)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmSetFocus(Widget.java:2402)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_SETFOCUS(Control.java:4792)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_SETFOCUS(Canvas.java:448)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_SETFOCUS(Decorations.java:1748)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4229)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1598)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2038)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
 at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:230)
 at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1194)
 at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2010-07-12 16:55:02.046
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2010-07-12 16:55:09.781
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
!SESSION 2010-07-12 17:17:04.234 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2010-07-12 17:17:05.359
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 4 2010-07-12 17:17:05.843
!MESSAGE Unable to read variable and containers file
!STACK 0
java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$VariablesAndContainersLoadHelper.loadInt(JavaModelManager.java:3344)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$VariablesAndContainersLoadHelper.loadProjects(JavaModelManager.java:3373)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$VariablesAndContainersLoadHelper.load(JavaModelManager.java:3212)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.loadVariablesAndContainers(JavaModelManager.java:3049)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.startup(JavaModelManager.java:4705)
 at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.start(JavaCore.java:5048)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:783)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:774)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:370)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:284)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:417)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:106)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:453)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:469)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:338)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:232)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1197)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.addModifyListener(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:90)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.getModifyListeners(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:186)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.firePreApplyEvent(PreferencesService.java:440)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyPreferences(PreferencesService.java:122)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.read(ProjectPreferences.java:234)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ProjectPreferences.updatePreferences(ProjectPreferences.java:302)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.updateMetadataFiles(File.java:414)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.RefreshLocalVisitor.visit(RefreshLocalVisitor.java:297)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.accept(UnifiedTree.java:108)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refreshResource(FileSystemResourceManager.java:824)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refresh(FileSystemResourceManager.java:808)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refreshRoot(FileSystemResourceManager.java:855)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.refresh(FileSystemResourceManager.java:801)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.refreshLocal(Resource.java:1661)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.refresh.RefreshJob.runInWorkspace(RefreshJob.java:166)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2010-07-12 17:20:11.921
!MESSAGE Could not create action delegate for id: org.maven.ide.eclipse.editor.RenameProjectAction

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2010-07-12 17:20:11.921
!MESSAGE Internal plug-in action delegate error on creation.
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:469)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:259)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.createDelegate(PluginAction.java:122)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:275)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.<init>(PluginAction.java:112)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectPluginAction.<init>(ObjectPluginAction.java:83)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionDescriptor.createAction(ActionDescriptor.java:272)
```

I can't explain that to myself, there are a lot of reasons. Maybe somebody had simialar problems and can help me with that.

#### Update:

:-( After 30 minutes it startet leaking again :-(

It seems like Eclipse remains in an endless loop. The task 'Eclipse' uses ~50% of my CPU continously.

That's very strange. Here is my eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
```

Maybe there is a problem ?!? Does somebody has an Idea?

EDIT: I need to say that it's better. That problem occurs very rarely.

#### Update 2:

May Somebaody help me with configuring my eclips.ini please. So that I can work with JDK 6-21... Or mshould I maybe use an older version?

That's it so far:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20100503
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-XX:PermSize=128M
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
```

**Okay I followed shipmaster's recommend and posted another question:
[Trouble with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244025/trouble-with-eclipse)**

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding updates as answers.

Comment: Per your updates I dont think it is the same problem. Permgen memory errors will cause an exception, not cause eclipse to go into some endless loop. I suggest you look at the eclipse log and maybe post another question.

Answer (score 10):

Another option, that has worked for me, is to adding in **Run->Debug configurations...->(Your Maven build)->JRE tab->VM arguments** some VM arguments:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewSize=128m
```

Hope this help...

**Updated:**

Or even, you can add the same arguments to:

**Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs->(*Your preferred JDK or the JRE used by your Maven instance*)->Default VM Arguments**

Comment: Yes. The memory limits set in ini are ignored by VM.

Answer (score 6):

You need to increase your max perm size by passing -XX:MaxPermSize=256m in eclipse.ini

Note: For Helios and your version of java, please use the above, using the other argument (launcher.XXMaxPermSize) will not work because of a bug.

See more in the following links:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=319514

Answer (score 0):

I had a seem a similar issue with my eclipse galileo. It was working fine all this while with JDK 6 update 3, until I had updated my jdk 1.6.0_21.

When I changed my JDK path to point to Jdk 6 update 3, it started working fine.

Hope this help !!!

Thanks,
Amit Chhajed