# Trouble with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I installed Eclipse Helios and m2eclipse. Next I created a maven project. Now Eclipse goes crazy. It leaks all the time, goes in endless loops (continously 50% CPU), throws PermGen Space Errors and crashes. I can't work.

I tried to substitute the JDK with an older version, the same with maven and the same with eclipse. I also changed the size of my PermGen Space.

Has somebody an Idea what's wrong? Or does that remembers somebody about a known bug? May there be a problem with my Windows XP?

Her are some Errors from my Workspace/Metadata/.log:

```
eclipse.buildId=I20100608-0911
java.version=1.6.0_20
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m


!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2010-07-13 14:40:21.758
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space


!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2010-07-13 14:39:37.741
!MESSAGE Internal plug-in action delegate error on creation.
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.createDelegate(PluginAction.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.selectionChanged(PluginAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.<init>(PluginAction.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ObjectPluginAction.<init>(ObjectPluginAction.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ActionDescriptor.createAction(ActionDescriptor.java:272)


!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2010-07-13 14:39:18.037
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Processing Dirty Regions".
!STACK 0
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: org/apache/xerces/util/DefaultErrorHandler, method: printError signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/xerces/xni/parser/XMLParseException;)V) Illegal constant pool index
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.configurePipeline(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration.configurePipeline(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.XMLValidator.validate(XMLValidator.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.eclipse.Validator.validate(Validator.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.eclipse.Validator.validate(Validator.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.core.AbstractNestedValidator.validate(AbstractNestedValidator.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.validation.core.AbstractNestedValidator.validateInJob(AbstractNestedValidator.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.validation.DelegatingSourceValidator.validate(DelegatingSourceValidator.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.validator.ReconcileStepForValidator.validate(ReconcileStepForValidator.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.validator.ReconcileStepForValidator.reconcileModel(ReconcileStepForValidator.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconcileStep.reconcile(AbstractReconcileStep.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.validator.ValidatorStrategy.reconcile(ValidatorStrategy.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.DocumentRegionProcessor.process(DocumentRegionProcessor.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor.process(StructuredRegionProcessor.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.DirtyRegionProcessor.run(DirtyRegionProcessor.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)


!ENTRY org.maven.ide.eclipse 4 0 2010-07-13 14:39:07.755
!MESSAGE Unable to update index for central|http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
!STACK 0
java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:137)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:58)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.IndexDataReader.<init>(IndexDataReader.java:40)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.unpackIndexData(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:562)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.loadIndexDirectory(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:252)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.access$300(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:74)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater$LuceneIndexAdaptor.setIndexFile(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:815)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:995)
    at org.sonatype.nexus.index.updater.DefaultIndexUpdater.fetchAndUpdateIndex(DefaultIndexUpdater.java:159)
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.index.NexusIndexManager.updateRemoteIndex(NexusIndexManager.java:1077)
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.index.NexusIndexManager.updateIndex(NexusIndexManager.java:1015)
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.index.NexusIndexManager$1.run(NexusIndexManager.java:631)
    at org.maven.ide.eclipse.internal.index.IndexUpdaterJob.run(IndexUpdaterJob.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)


!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2010-07-13 12:19:01.578
!MESSAGE Ignored reentrant call while viewer is busy. This is only logged once per viewer instance, but similar calls will still be ignored.
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.checkBusy(ColumnViewer.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnViewer.refresh(ColumnViewer.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.refresh(CommonViewer.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonViewer.refresh(CommonViewer.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider$3.run(ResourceExtensionContentProvider.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider.runUpdates(ResourceExtensionContentProvider.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionContentProvider.processDelta(ResourceExtensionContentProvider.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.ui.model.WorkbenchContentProvider.resourceChanged(WorkbenchContentProvider.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$2.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1984)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.initializeAllContainers(JavaModelManager.java:2653)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager.getClasspathContainer(JavaModelManager.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.getClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:2705)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2645)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.resolveClasspath(JavaProject.java:2783)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(JavaProject.java:1915)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.buildStructure(JavaProject.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:252)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getChildren(JavaElement.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoots(JavaProject.java:1803)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getPackageFragmentRoots(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.StandardJavaElementContentProvider.getChildren(StandardJavaElementContentProvider.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerContentProvider.getChildren(PackageExplorerContentProvider.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.getChildren(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.navigator.JavaNavigatorContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(JavaNavigatorContentProvider.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.extensions.SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.getPipelinedChildren(SafeDelegateTreeContentProvider.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.pipelineChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.access$1(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider$1.run(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.internalGetChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.getChildren(NavigatorContentServiceContentProvider.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getRawChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1348)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.getRawChildren(TreeViewer.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.getFilteredChildren(StructuredViewer.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.getSortedChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$1.run(AbstractTreeViewer.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:778)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.createChildren(TreeViewer.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.createChildren(AbstractTreeViewer.java:749)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleTreeExpand(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1444)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer.handleTreeExpand(TreeViewer.java:952)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer$4.treeExpanded(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1455)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.wmNotifyChild(Tree.java:7408)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:5096)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:1887)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:4726)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4215)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.callWindowProc(Tree.java:1536)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.WM_LBUTTONDOWN(Tree.java:6303)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4195)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(Tree.java:5844)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2629)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2593)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2427)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

---

### Update

I installed Eclipse + m2eclipse with Pulse. And it works now. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently done to same thing - installed Helios with m2eclipse (on XP) with nothing of the above happening. So it's your local problem. Try to:

- delete your installation and make it anew
- try not *creating* a maven project, but rather creating a simple project, adding a pom, and enabling maven capabilities (via right click)

Answer (score 1):

Check your eclipse.ini file.  From your posted log I see this:

> Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   **-XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m**

Those are supposed to be VM arguments, not program arguments.  If they were properly specified as vm arguments then you shouldn't see them there in the log.

Make sure they are below the `-vmargs` in the eclipse.ini file.  Also make sure every argument is on its own line.  Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse) for examples.

Also well, if you are running Java 6 update 21, take a look at [this](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2010/07/permgen-problems-and-running-eclipse-on.html).

Answer (score 1):

I was facing exactly same problem except that mine was 64 bit OS and 64 bit eclipse with 64 bit JDK 1.6.0_26 update.
After refering to various forums, I re-installed the JDK to an older version.. JDK 1.6.0_17 and got rid of the Out of memory error.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It also helps to install the 32 bit and 64 bit JDKs. I did this and it fixed my eclipse perm gen space errors for some reason...

Answer (score 0):

Another option, that has worked for me, is to adding in **Run->Debug configurations...->(Your Maven build)->JRE tab->VM arguments** some VM arguments:

```
-Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:NewSize=128m
```

Hope this help...

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error and found it was due to the fact that I renamed my eclipse executable from default name when unzipped -> 'eclipse.exe' . The new name contained spaces, so not sure if it is related....